# Astropy - Ra, dec to AltAz conversion (in degrees)

Tags: python, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, astropy, degrees

Good evening,

I have come across an example where Ra, dec are converted to AltAz using time. The code is as follows:

```
from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation,SkyCoord
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import AltAz

observing_location = EarthLocation(lat='52.2532', lon='351.63910339111703', height=100*u.m)  
observing_time = Time('2017-02-05 20:12:18')  
aa = AltAz(location=observing_location, obstime=observing_time)

coord = SkyCoord('4h42m', '-38d6m50.8s')
coord.transform_to(aa)
```

This example is quite explanatory however when I tried to find which keyword I need to use
instead of 'obstime' (in order to identify degrees instead of time) I found no information at all. Do you have any idea what needs to be done?
Thank you

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure what you mean.  Degrees of what instead of time?

Comment: You can find all the documentation for `AltAz` at https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.AltAz.html  Maybe you're looking for `temperature`?

Comment: Yes, I mean that time can be expressed in degrees (0-360) instead of a 24h scale

Comment: Oh I see.  In that case you would still use `obstime` since `Time` is quite generic and be instantiated in many different ways.  In this case you would still need a date as well.  I don't think what you're asking is one of the supported [Time Formats](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/index.html#time-format) but you could implement a new one.